# Groovy XmlSlurper with special characters in node names

Tags: xml, groovy

I am trying to use the groovy xml slurper to slurp the following XML, with the goal being getting to the:

```
<message>ARoute</message>
```

tag.

```
<org.kie.server.api.model.ServiceResponse>
<type>SUCCESS</type>
<msg>Container container2 successfully called.</msg>
<result class="string">
    <execution-results>
    <result identifier="helloWorld">
<com.me.testproject.HelloWorld>
  <message>ARoute</message>
</com.me.testproject.HelloWorld>
</result>
<fact-handle identifier="helloWorld" external-form="0:1:1985641387:1985641387:2:DEFAULT:NON_TRAIT:com.me.testproject.HelloWorld"/>
</execution-results></result>
</org.kie.server.api.model.ServiceResponse>
```

When I just use the following gpath:

```
def response = new XmlSlurper().parseText(payload)
def result = response.result
println( "Output is " + result)
```

I get the following (which I expect)

```
Output is <execution-results>
 <result identifier="helloWorld">
<com.me.testproject.HelloWorld>
  <message>ARoute</message>
</com.me.testproject.HelloWorld>
</result>
<fact-handle identifier="helloWorld" external-  form="0:37:1288414012:1288414012:74:DEFAULT:NON_TRAIT:com.me.testproject.HelloWorld"/>
</execution-results>
```

However when I attempt to parse the execution-results something appears to be off, my understanding was becuase of the hyphon in the xml node name, I should put it in characters but that doesnt seem to do the trick:

```
def response = new XmlSlurper().parseText(payload)
def result = response.result.'execution-results'
println( "The type is " + result)
```

Outputs:
     The type is

How would I go about drilling deeper into the XML message to get to the message tag?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

By default, the `toString()` of a gpath expression is equivalent to the `text()` method: it only show the text content of the nodes matched by the expression. In short: the expression has worked, but your println didn't show what you expected.

If you wants the content as xml, you can use `groovy.xml.XmlUtil.serialize(result)`

Comment: Thanks for the response, sure enough adding that in makes it work. Whats also worth noting is I noticed that my XML was some times coming in as escaped, unescaping the XML string using org.apache.commons.lang3.StringEscapeUtils and then parsing it also fixed a few issues.